# Alea CUDA DeviceMapModule much slower than handwritten kernel

Tags: aleagpu

I tried to use the DeviceMapModule and the DeviceMap2Module for simple mapping operations.
To my surprise it is about 2x slower than writing the kernel by hand.
For the hand written kernel I did not do anything special. I just copied the Getting Started Square kernel and modified it to do sigmoid.

Below is 2 versions of the code:

First the slow version:

```
type SigmoidModule(size) =
    inherit Module(size, size) // Note Module is my own abstract class that defines the forward/backward interface.

    [<ReflectedDefinition; AOTCompile>]
    let sigmoid' s y = (1.0f-s) * s * y

    [<ReflectedDefinition; AOTCompile>]
    let sigmoid x = 1.0f / (1.0f + __nv_expf (-x))

    let forwardMap = new DeviceMapModule<float32, float32>(GPUModuleTarget.DefaultWorker, <@ sigmoid @>)
    let backwardMap = new DeviceMap2Module<float32, float32, float32>(
                        GPUModuleTarget.DefaultWorker, <@ sigmoid' @>)

    let mutable activation = Matrix.ZeroCreate 1 size

    override m.Forward (fwd:Matrix) = 
        assert(fwd.Cols = size)
        if activation.Rows <> fwd.Rows then
            activation.Data.Dispose()
            activation <- Matrix.ZeroCreate fwd.Rows fwd.Cols

        forwardMap.Map(activation.Data.Ptr, fwd.Data.Ptr, fwd.Cols * fwd.Rows)
        activation

    override m.Backward (dy:Matrix) = 
        assert(dy.Cols = size)
        assert(activation.Rows = dy.Rows)

        backwardMap.Map(activation.Data.Ptr, activation.Data.Ptr, dy.Data.Ptr, dy.Cols * dy.Rows)
        activation

    interface IDisposable with
        member m.Dispose() = 
            forwardMap.Dispose()
            backwardMap.Dispose()
            activation.Data.Dispose()
```

Now the fast version:

```
type SigmoidModuleFast(size) =
inherit Module(size, size)
let sigmoid' s y = (1.0f-s) * s * y
let worker = Worker.Default

[<ReflectedDefinition; AOTCompile>]
static let sigmoidKernel (outputs:deviceptr<float32>) (inputs:deviceptr<float32>) n =
    let start = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x
    let stride = gridDim.x * blockDim.x
    let sigmoid x = 1.0f / (1.0f + __nv_expf (-x))

    let mutable i = start 
    while i < n do
        outputs.[i] <- sigmoid(inputs.[i])
        i <- i + stride

[<ReflectedDefinition; AOTCompile>]
static let sigmoidPrimeKernel (outputs:deviceptr<float32>) (input:deviceptr<float32>) (dy:deviceptr<float32>) n =
    let start = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x
    let stride = gridDim.x * blockDim.x

    let mutable i = start 
    while i < n do
        let s = input.[i]
        let y = dy.[i]
        outputs.[i] <- (1.0f-s) * s * y
        i <- i + stride

let mutable activation = Matrix.ZeroCreate 1 size
let mutable lp = LaunchParam(1, size)

override m.Forward (fwd:Matrix) = 
    assert(fwd.Cols = size)
    if activation.Rows <> fwd.Rows then
        activation.Data.Dispose()
        activation <- Matrix.ZeroCreate fwd.Rows fwd.Cols
        let threads = fwd.Rows * fwd.Cols
        if threads < 1024 then
            lp <- LaunchParam(1, threads)
        else
            let blockSize = 256
            let numSm = worker.Device.Attributes.MULTIPROCESSOR_COUNT
            let gridSize = Math.Min(16 * numSm, divup threads blockSize)
            lp <- new LaunchParam(gridSize, blockSize)

    worker.Launch <@ sigmoidKernel @> lp activation.Data.Ptr fwd.Data.Ptr (fwd.Cols*fwd.Rows)
    activation

override m.Backward (dy:Matrix) = 
    assert(dy.Cols = size)
    assert(activation.Rows = dy.Rows)

    worker.Launch <@ sigmoidPrimeKernel @> lp activation.Data.Ptr activation.Data.Ptr dy.Data.Ptr (dy.Cols*dy.Rows)
    activation

interface IDisposable with
    member m.Dispose() = 
        activation.Data.Dispose()
```

Here is some information about my system:

- Name  Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4590 CPU @ 3.30GHz
- Architecture  x64
- Frequency 3,300 MHz
- Number of Cores   4
- Page Size 4,096
- Total Physical Memory 8,050.00 MB
- Available Physical Memory 902.00 MB
- Hybrid Graphics Enabled   False
- Version Name  Windows 10 Pro
- Version Number    10.0.10586
- Nsight Version    5.1.0.16062
- Visual Studio Version 14.0
- GPU: NVidia GTX 980 Ti
- .NET CLR: .NET 4.6.

Answer (score 2):

I'm no expert on GPU programming but have a basic understanding. I saw this question while evaluating Alea GPU.

The NVidia GTX 980 Ti has 2816 cores. With a blockSize of 256 that gives a grid size of 2816 / 256 = 11.

The Alea Community/Basic Developer library allows up to 2688 cores. If the Alea library sets a blockSize of 256 (this is a guess) that gives a gridSize of 10.5.

Could it be that the job is being split into two? The first run saturating the 2688 core limit and then the rest running on 2816 - 2688 = 128 cores?